# Method of Undetermined Coeffients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am using the method of undetermined coefficients to solve 2nd Order Differential Equations and at times it can be messy. Are there any methods that are more efficient that the method of undetermined coefficients?

Comment: It really depends on the differential equation.

Comment: Take this with a pinch of salt, but method of undetermined coefficients is the most practical way in solving inhomogeneous 2nd order ODE.

Comment: Maybe the Laplace transform